# how can i fix composer

Tags: github, composer-php, flarum

` - Downloading flarumtr/flarum-ext-mobile-search (v1.2)

- Downloading itnt/flarum-uitab (v0.4.2)
  0/2 [>---------------------------]   0%    Failed to download itnt/flarum-uitab from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/littlegolden/flarum-uitab/zipball/f6f24b394a9ae3e7867ee149c9ea8da7fd04b36f" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 ):
  {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing itnt/flarum-uitab (v0.4.2) into cache
  2/2 [============================] 100%
  In Git.php line 471:

Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'https://ghp...Clq:x-oauth-basic@github.com/littlegolden/flarum-uitab.git' '/root/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-littlegolden-flarum-uitab.git/'

Cloning into bare repository '/root/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-littlegolden-flarum-uitab.git'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/littlegolden/flarum-uitab.git/' not found

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [...]

`

I can't install Flarum plugin, it doesn't pull data from github

Comment: You should provide more details on what you are doing.

Comment: Sounds like anything could not be found. According to packagist.org, `itnt/flarum-uitab` has seen its last update more than a year ago

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following situation: Last year, you've managed to install the Flarum software and you're proudly running your online-community since then.

Half a year ago one of your communities' fellow users went famous writing a forum post linking to a very cool website.

Unfortunately six weeks later that cool website went offline and never came back.

Now how could you fix your forum? Well, there is not much you can do about it. Either there is a new link to the cool website (e.g. just the named reference changed), then you'd need to research it and update the forum post with the new link or if there is no alternative available, you could not fix your forum at all and as the post is not useful without a working link, remove it altogether in moderation.

---

This is similar with Composer and abandoned Composer packages like *"`itnt/flarum-uitab`"*. You can either find a replacement or you can't fix it, that is you need to remove it from the list of packages you require.

---

If your question is how to prevent Composer from downloading that abandoned package in the first place, you have to find out *why* `itnt/flarum-uitab` is installed, as this depends on your project configuration and you have not shared it.

To do so, run the `composer why` sub-command, e.g.:

```
$ composer why itnt/flarum-uitab
<package>  <version>  requires  itnt/flarum-uitab (<version-constraint>)
```

If `<package>` in the output is your own project (the so called root package), use the `composer remove itnt/flarum-uitab` command to remove the requirement.

If `<package>` in your output is not, run `composer update` first in case you didn't yet. If it still errors, check with `composer why` again which `<package>`  causes it to install. Then obtain the support information for that package and check if the issue has already been reported. If not, report it.

Alternatively you can also use `composer remove <package>` for every package that causes `itnt/flarum-uitab` to install in your project, if you don't plan to use that package any longer.